# Power series rings and the formal generic fibre

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, deformation-theory, galois-representations

Let $S = K[[S_1,\ldots,S_n]]$ and consider $d$ elements 
\begin{equation*}
f_1,\ldots,f_d \in S[[X_1,\ldots,X_d]]
\end{equation*} 
and the prime ideal ${\frak P} \colon\!= (f_1,\ldots,f_d)$ generated by them.

Suppose that ${\frak P}$ satisfies the following three conditions$\colon$

1. ${\frak P} \cap S = 0$.
2. ${\mathrm{ht}}({\frak P}) = d$.
3. Neither of $\overline{f_1},\ldots,\overline{f_d} \in K[[X_1,\ldots,X_d]]$ is zero.

(The condition 3. is equivalent to that every $f_i$ contains at least one term $c_{e_1,\ldots,e_d}X_1^{e_1} \ldots X_d^{e_d}$ such that $c_{e_1,\ldots,e_d} \notin (S_1,\ldots,S_n)$.)

### Q. Is the ring $S[[X_1,\ldots,X_d]]/{\frak P}$ necessariy finite over $S$?

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $n=d=2$, $f_1=X_1-S_1$, $f_2=X_1-S_2X_2$, and check. (Observe in particular that $S[[X_1,X_2]]/(f_1,f_2)$ is isomorphic to $S[[X_2]]/(S_1-S_2X_2)$ as an $S$-algebra, and to $K[[S_2,X_2]]$ as a ring).